# WPF rendering problem

Tags: wpf

Suddenly my wpf application showing forms which i am showing as Dialog are crashing (not showing properly)

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2r26pft&s=7

any idea how to restart wpf rendering engine?

---

I am closing this question:

---

I don't the exact problem but I create my login UI from scratch by putting the same old xaml and now it is working as it should, GOD bless Microsoft! :)

http://i56.tinypic.com/2ex0u2s.png

Comment: even after restarting my PC didn't solve the problem, my form @ design looks like this http://i52.tinypic.com/2rer0oo.png

Comment: Maybe you should include some XAML code.

Comment: my whole window http://ShareText.org/ZWN

Answer (score 0):

looks like some serious dropshadow!!!

with that style every border gets a dropshadow. I doubt that is what you want. try removing it!

(I mean that style: `<Style TargetType="Border"> ...`)

Comment: thanx, i removed all styles even from TextBox+PasswordBox along with Border but same view

Comment: @Adnan Badar when I first saw your Image I thought to myself: uhh, dropshadows. Then I saw your code => ahh, dropshadows. If I paste your code in Kaxaml it looks like in your pic. If I then remove that style, everything looks as expected (ie right). So please try once again to remove the `<Style TargetType="Border">` within `<Window.Resources> `

Comment: dear i remove all the resource tag, still same

Comment: i think now its a big mess, i just remove even the border tag and moved my grid as the first control, still same issue

Comment: @Adnan and this is only happening with your application? It's not like your graphics card is broke or something?

Comment: btw i put all my xaml on XamlPad(with dropshadows) and its running fine http://i53.tinypic.com/ayves0.png

Comment: hmm. quite strange I admit. So if it works in XamlPad it seems to be something else in your application. Have you set some global styles in you Application.Resources ?

Comment: first i was, but now i did
<Application x:Class="Application"                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="frmMain.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Comment: I don't the exact problem but I create my login UI from scratch by putting the same old xaml and now it is working as it should, GOD bless Microsoft! :)

http://i56.tinypic.com/2ex0u2s.png

MARKUS Thank you so much for your great contribution + time,

Regards,
Adnan